# mathjax can't convert inline math formula in flatpages

Tags: python, flask, markdown, mathjax, flask-flatpages

I found mathjax doesn't convert inline formula in [flatpages](http://flask-flatpages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) of my flask app.

The simple markdown text is like:

```
this is inline math formula \$x^2+y^2=1\$, can not display normally.  

this is block formula is ok.   
$$ 
x^2 + y^2 = 1  
$$
```

The flatpages configurations may be useful.

```
FLATPAGES_ROOT = os.path.join(BASEDIR, 'app', 'posts')
FLATPAGES_EXTENSION ='.md'
FLATPAGES_MARKDOWN_EXTENSIONS = ['fenced_code']
```

mathjax is put in my flask templates:

```
<script async src="//cdn.bootcss.com/mathjax/2.6.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
```

I think there may be some conflict between markdown and mathjax when parsing markdown text.
I hope someone could help my figure out this problem.

Answer (score 1):

After search and reading mathjax documents. I found the solution is to specify the inline delimiters.

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\(","\)"] ],
      processEscapes: true
    },
    "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
  });
</script>
```

mathjax take **$...$** and **(...)** as inline delimiters, and it works. 
I doubt why mathjax don't accept **$...$** as default inline delimiter.

[The tex2jax Preprocessor](https://mathjax-chinese-doc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options/tex2jax.html)